# Flutter Unit8List Resize Photo

Tags: flutter

I want to change the size of the photos I take with flutter unit8list as http extension, for example, the size of the photo is 1280x800, but I want to adjust its size manually. Is this possible?

```
    String imgurl = "http://.....jpg";
        
    
    Uint8List bytes = (await NetworkAssetBundle(Uri.parse(imgurl),)
      .load(imgurl))
      .buffer
      .asUint8List();
```